# How to add a floor to the world?

Tags: ros, gazebo-9

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I have a small robot which I want to spawn it on a ramp that I have created. Everytime I spawn it there, due to the inertia the robot rolls down the ramp and then falls down into the emptness where ramp is present. So i wanted to firwst launch a ground_plane on which later I want to launch a ramp, so that even if robot rolls down the ramp, it doesnt fall down into emptyness. Can anyone please help me how to do that ?

I have tried using two include statements one for each model and yet only the first include statement is being considered while launching. I am launching it using roslaunch.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/23808/how-to-add-a-floor-to-the-world?/) by [microbot](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/9644/microbot/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2019-09-20

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kumpakri](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6511/kumpakri/) on 2019-09-20**:
You can add the ground model into your world

```
<sdf version="1.4"> 
  <world name="world"> 
      <include> 
          <uri>model://ground_plane</uri> 
      </include> 
      <include> 
          <uri>model://sun</uri> 
      </include>
  </world> 
</sdf>
```

**Comment by [microbot](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/9644/microbot/) on 2019-09-20**:
Thank you, I have did that before although i forgot to add appropriate scale, now I fixed it and its running, thank you.

**Comment by [kumpakri](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6511/kumpakri/) on 2019-09-20**:
I have edited the question title and added the answer so that other users can find this thread useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Adding ground to WORLD file:

```
<sdf version="1.4"> 
  <world name="world"> 
      <include> 
          <uri>model://ground_plane</uri> 
      </include> 
      <include> 
          <uri>model://sun</uri> 
      </include>
      ...
  </world> 
</sdf>
```

---

Originally posted by [kumpakri](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6511/kumpakri/) with karma: 755 on 2019-09-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0